# Proving at least one number $\le 1/4$

Tags: inequality, products, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

How to prove that at least one of $\alpha(1-\beta),\beta(1-\gamma),\gamma(1-\alpha)$ is lesser than $1/4$ given that $\alpha,\beta,\gamma\in(0,1)$

The original problem was proving at least one triangle (except the middle one) formed by dividing an equilateral triangle into four triangles is at least 4 times smaller than the original which I simplified to above. Don't know how to proceed, any hints?

Comment: Isn't the third number $\gamma(1-\alpha)$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen yep, you're correct, gonna fix it

Comment: Note that the product of these numbers is $\leq (1/4)^3$.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek got the answer, although, everything is obvious for someone educated enough

Comment: @AFalseName I haven't noticed you exclude the middle triangle. That's why I edited  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WLOG let $\alpha \ge \gamma$. Then we have:

$$\gamma(1-\alpha) \le \alpha(1-\alpha) = \alpha - \alpha^2 = \frac 14 - \left(\frac 12 - \alpha\right)^2 \le \frac 14$$

Comment: You can not assume that $\alpha\geq \beta\geq\gamma$ because the given is cyclic and it's not symmetric.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg You're right. Anyway assuming $\alpha \ge \gamma$ is enough.

Comment: Yes of course! +1

Answer (score 0):

Because by AM-GM
$$\prod_{cyc}\alpha(1-\beta)=\prod_{cyc}\alpha(1-\alpha)\leq\prod_{cyc}\left(\frac{\alpha+1-\alpha}{2}\right)^2=\frac{1}{64}$$ and we'll got a contradiction if
$$\alpha(1-\beta)>\frac{1}{4},$$ 
$$\beta(1-\gamma)>\frac{1}{4}$$ and 
$$\gamma(1-\alpha)>\frac{1}{4},$$ which gives
$$\prod_{cyc}\alpha(1-\beta)>\frac{1}{64}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Assume not. Let $s:=\min\{\alpha,\beta,\gamma, 1-\alpha,1-\beta,1-\gamma\}$, so clearly $0<s\le \frac12$. Then 
$$\frac14<\alpha(1-\beta)\le\alpha(1-s),\\
\frac14<(1-\alpha)\gamma\le (1-\alpha)(1-s),$$
and likewise
$$ \frac14<\beta(1-s),\quad\frac14<(1-\beta)(1-s),\quad\frac14<\gamma(1-s),\quad\frac14<(1-\gamma)(1-s)$$so that also

$$ \frac14<s(1-s)=\frac14-\left(s-\frac12\right)^2$$
conradiction.

Answer (score -1):

$\alpha(1-\beta)\times\beta(1-\gamma)\times\gamma(1-\alpha) = \alpha(1-\alpha)\times\beta(1-\beta)\times\gamma(1-\gamma)=X$

Since $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are independent we can find maximum value of $\alpha(1-\alpha)=1/4$ at $\alpha=1/2$. Similarly for other two.
Therefore $X \leq 1/16$.

If product of $\alpha(1-\beta),\beta(1-\gamma),\gamma(1-\alpha)$ is $\leq 1/16$, atleast one of $\alpha(1-\beta),\beta(1-\gamma),\gamma(1-\alpha)$ is $\leq1/4$ and atleast one of $\alpha(1-\beta),\beta(1-\gamma),\gamma(1-\alpha)$ is $\geq1/4$. *$($Since at $\alpha=\beta=\gamma=1/2$ all three are $1/4)$*